# need hep with awk if equal to or less than

Tags: linux, shell, awk, scripting

Similar to a previous post I made, I am trying the following:

Myfile.txt contains:

```
$TTL 600
@            IN    SOA  dns1.mysite.com. root.localhost.  (
                      2020042101   ; serial
                      1h           ; refresh
                      30m          ; retry
                      1w           ; expiry
                      30m)         ; minimum
               IN     NS    localhost.

dns1.mysite.com    IN      A       172.16.1.18
dns2.mysite.com    IN      A       172.16.2.18

; Redirect this site to localhost to block
; List last consolidated on 12/11/2018

; DNS Blocks
*.mad   IN      CNAME   *.

beans.com       A       127.0.0.1 ; this is a test case

*.000webhostapp.com     A       127.0.0.1
*.00h5.com      A       127.0.0.1
*.00webhostapp.com      A       127.0.0.1
```

myscript.sh contains:

```
date=$ (date '+%y%m%d'01)
ydate=$ (date -d yesterday '+%y%m%d'01)

awk "{sub(/$ydate/,$date)}1" myfile.txt > tempt.txt && mv temp.txt myfile.txt
```

As it stands now, this works IF the date in the file matches only yesterdays date. What I am now looking to do is match if it is yesterdays date or before, and if it is, replace it with $date, then overwrite the file.

I know that awk can do this with "n1 -le n2", but I cant get it to work inline with the operations that I am using.

Can anyone help me in getting this to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `<=` comparison. You can then reassign the field with the replacement.

```
awk -v yesterday="$date" -v today="$ydate" '/; serial/ && $1 <= yesterday { sub(/[0-9]+/, today) }1' myfile.txt > temp.txt
```

And it's generally better to assign `awk` variables with `-v` rather than substituting shell variables into the script.